# Stata, Python: Downloading files from a FTP site in Stata (or in Python)

Tags: python, ftp, stata

ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/BG/2010/

I have to download some zip files that look like "tl_2010_`st'_bg10.zip" where`st' is 2-digit state fips code. How should I write a Stata code to download those selected files into a folder? Is Stata capable of getting files from a FTP site? If not, what about in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in Stata 13 (haven't tested earlier versions):

```
. copy ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/BG/2010/tl_2010_01005_bg10.zip bg10.zip 

. unzipfile bg10.zip
inflating: tl_2010_01005_bg10.dbf
inflating: tl_2010_01005_bg10.prj
inflating: tl_2010_01005_bg10.shp
inflating: tl_2010_01005_bg10.shp.xml
inflating: tl_2010_01005_bg10.shx
successfully unzipped bg10.zip to current directory
```

However, I think you will need something else to read those files.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a previous answer, `copy` and `unzipfile` will do the work. For multiple files (appropriately named) you can try something like:

```
forvalues i = 1/100 {
    copy http://example.com/download`i'.zip download`i'.zip
    unzipfile download`i'.zip
}
```

Given the file types you are working with (i.e. .shp and .dbf) you might want to try the user written command `shp2dta`. Run `ssc describe shp2dta` to get a description and `ssc install shp2dta` to install.

You can also use "standard" shell commands with/without Stata, and of course, you could use virtually any general purpose language (e.g. Python) for the task.

All this is documented in the Stata Blog:

http://blog.stata.com/2010/12/01/automating-web-downloads-and-file-unzipping/

You should take a look at that and the links therein.

Comment: Thanks. And I will check the shp2dta package. But it seems that Stata does not do spatial analyses very well -- in comparison with R.